# How do I center everything inside 2 bootstrap columns? (col-md-6 and col-md-6)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I have something like this

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6>
          <form class="form-group-sm">
            <input />
            <button type="submit"></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-md-6> 
          <form class="form-group-sm">
            <input />
            <button type="submit"></button>
          </form>
        </div>>
      </div>
```

2 columns side by side, I'm trying to figure out a way to center the forms, input, and button inside each column but cant seem too figure out how.

```
     <form method="POST" action="./createProduct" class="form-group-sm" >

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="t" class="col-md-8 control-label">Product Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input name="productType" id="t"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sn" class="col-md-8 control-label">Material Cost PerSqFoot</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input name="matCostSqf" id="sn"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="snum" class="col-md-8 control-label">Labor Cost PerSqFoot</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input name="laborCostSqf" id="snum" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <br />
                    <button class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg center-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap has a default class for that called `text-center`.

Just add the `text-center` class to your `col-` divs like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">

    -- your content --

</div>
```

---

**P.S.** You forgot to properly close the column divs. Do make sure you close them always

Comment: Could you check my edit? The text center almost works but its still too the left a little bit. im guessing it has something to do with my form group sizes?

Comment: Hold on, let me check it out.

Comment: @BrennanBennett So the second snippet with the form is in the first or second `col-md-6` from the first snippet?

Comment: I got it figured out. the text-center was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help Brennan :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Your markup contains some errors like an extra closing div and a missing double cotes for the class attribute : class="col-md-6>
here is the solution you can use the bootstrap class "text-center"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <form class="form-group-sm">
        <input />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-6 text-center"> 
      <form class="form-group-sm">
        <input />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[here is a pen](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: Yeah I manually put all those in in the text box lol thanks though.